# Faster growing function than the fast growing heiarchy under Church-Kleene?

Tags: computability, ordinals

Is there a computable function that grows faster than any function in a fast growing hierarchy with index less than the Church–Kleene ordinal, where computable fundamental sequences are used?

If the answer is negative, is there any proof that can be referenced or provided?

Fast growing heiarchies are defined on their wiki page, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy.

As discussed in the comments, I do not think the particular fundamental sequences chosen will affect this question. If I am wrong on that point, please let me know.

Comment: What exactly is the definition of that fast-growing hierarchy? (The hierarchies I'm aware of only grow up to some fixed computable ordinal - e.g. Lob-Wainer, up to $\epsilon_0$.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I have added an edit that I think addresses your question, if not let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with you that the choice of fundamental sequences won't matter . . .

Comment: The Church-Kleene ordinal is the closure of 0 under successor and limits of computable sequences. Then if the computable sequence used to define an ordinal is used as the fundamental sequence, the fast growing hierarchy is the collection of functions given by the closure of successor under composition and diagnolization along any computable sequence. That collection of functions is broad enough to include any other definition of fundamental sequences, because it includes all the possible choices - all diagnolizations of computable sequences.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, On the other hand, it seems that with any definition of fundamental sequences that was narrow enough to miss any functions as described above, we could not actually define all recursive ordinals. That is not a proof, but it is why I expect the particular selection of fundamental sequences probably doesn't matter.

Comment: I agree with @NoahSchweber on this one.  It is not possible to define the fast growing hierarchy without fundamental sequences.  On the other hand, we now have a dupe.